# Composite Aggregation with After functionality

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am looking for a code snippet of After functionality usage with NEST lib.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_after.

Thanks in advance for the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `CompositeKey` from a previous composite aggregation as the `.After()` parameter for a new composite aggregation. For example

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Composite("composite_agg", c => c
            .Sources(so => so
                .DateHistogram("date", dh => dh
                    .Field("timestamp")
                    .Interval("1d")
                )
                .Terms("product", t => t
                    .Field("product")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

var compositeAgg = searchResponse.Aggregations.Composite("composite_agg");

searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Composite("composite_agg", c => c
            .Sources(so => so
                .DateHistogram("date", dh => dh
                    .Field("timestamp")
                    .Interval("1d")
                )
                .Terms("product", t => t
                    .Field("product")
                )
            )
            .After(compositeAgg.AfterKey) // <-- pass the after key from previous agg response
        )
    )
);
```

Assuming you're using Elasticsearch 6.x (which you must be to be using Composite Aggregation), please update NEST client to latest (6.6.0 at this time), as it contains a [bug fix for a `CompositeKey` with null values](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3575).